# Get WiFi networks programmatically in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to read the list of wifi networks in Xamarin.
Always get the following error:
WifiService: Neither user 10059 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE

The code that throws the exception is:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.WifiService);
        var networks = wifiManager.ConfiguredNetworks;
```

Platform specs:

MacOS HighSierra
Visual Studio for Mac
API Level 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After API 23 level you need to get permission from user to access WiFi state and some more data.

Get the user permission before making use of WiFiManager API would solve your issue.

Details about how to get permission from user can be found in this blog:
[Requesting Runtime Permissions in Android Marshmallow](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)